# projectFilesBackup folder in android studio project for latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

If we update the android studio with the latest version and update the plugin as well. A folder named `projectFilesBackup` created when we open our old android studio project in the latest android studio version.

My Question is why this folder created, why this is for and how long we should keep this folder in our project folder?

Answer (score 17):

When you accepted to continue in the Convert Project dialog, IntelliJ created this file.

> IntelliJ IDEA will back up old versions of project files to projectFilesBackUp folder within your project, so you could easily return to the old project version by replacing the project files with the old ones.

If the project is working correctly, you can delete the file.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/convert-project-dialog.html